# Qt can't find GL library

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have installed QT on 64 bit Centos. I got error below while building simple widget form application:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [untitled] Error 1
08:17:08: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.5 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Command below

```
locate *libGL.so*
```

Brigs

```
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

How to fix problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need the development files, not just the runtime files. When you specify the flag `-lGL`, the compiler will look for a libGL.so or a libGL.a file to link to.

In this case you would expect the /usr/lib64/libGL.so file to be present.

Run

```
  yum provides /usr/lib64/libGL.so
```

to find which package provides that file.  (Or a for a broader search, run `yum provides */libGL.so`)

Then install that package

```
  yum install mesa-libGL-devel
```